# Is there an output log/directory for sbatch error messages?

Tags: cluster-computing, job-scheduling, slurm, scientific-computing

I'm running an sbatch script, and it successfully submits.

`sbatch sbatch_script.sh`

`Submitted batch job 309376`

But it does not show up when I run `squeue -u <my_username>` and no output is generated.

Is there a way to check what went wrong? For instance, are some environment variables set/output log I can check?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sbatch output is written to a `slurm_{job_id}.out` on the node. Instead, you can manually specify the output file to the local directory (just do `myfile.out`). Then, this file will appear right in the local directory and contain the standard error and output streams.

My sbatch file:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1
#SBATCH --mem=12G
#SBATCH -p gpu
#SBATCH -c 8
#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH -o myfile.out
source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate acl2020
python  main.py --various args
```